# Get latest selected value

Tags: php, jquery

I have following checkbox code snippet where I have 2 checkbox selected now I select 3rd checkbox.Is there any way that latest (3rd value) value get? Currently, I am getting 3 values.

```
<div class="aRow">
<label>Attach Photo:</label>
<div class="form-multiselect binded binded-hover-intent" style="">
Select Attachment(s)<i></i>
<ul class="round-corners-bottom" style="top: 27px; display: none;">
    <li class="light-gray multi-header"><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox select-all-drop">All Options</label>
    </li><li><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" checked="checked">Option 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" checked="checked">Option 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox">Option 3</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reiterate your question. It doesn't make any sense now.

Comment: This will help you for sure https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/539709/Howplustoplusgetplusthepluslastplusselectedplusche

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Add "onclick='checkboxChanged(this)'" to each of your checkboxes. Then add a JavaScript function called checkboxChanged(chkbox).

Inside that function, chkbox will refer to the checkbox that was just clicked, and you can then see if it is checked or not and access the value.

You might also want to add an onkeyup event to handle keyboard-driven input.